# Empathy Chat automatically closes when I open it

Tags: empathy

I started Empathy from Ubuntu Terminal and the following Warning occurred:

```
folks-WARNING **: Error preparing persona store 'eds:1328683152.5139.1@developer-pc': Couldn't open address book ‘1328683152.5139.1@developer-pc’: Cannot open book: Could not create DesktopcouchSession object
Segmentation fault
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug with missing dependencies which are caught only on runtime.

Please install the package `libfolks-eds25` if not installed. Hopefully this should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Initially check the system log:

```
tail /var/log/apport.log
```

In my case "/usr/lib/empathy/empathy-chat" was crashing.

**To deal with it I open the chat from the terminal using the command:**

```
 /usr/lib/empathy/empathy-chat
```

and looked for the errors.

For me the solution was to remove some of the chats located here:

```
cd ~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs/
```

**Bottom line: Check the log file, run the program from the terminal, look in Google the error message**